# Java object notify parent class

Tags: java, android, class, notify

I am developing an [augmented-reality](/questions/tagged/augmented-reality) app in Android. I have one class which called AugmentedView, extends [view](/questions/tagged/view) and it is responsible to draw the markers. In the onDraw method when it detects collisions i want to notify the parent class which is the main class and contains the main gui to enable one button in the screen. I call the AugmentedView class in the onCreate of Main class with the following code:

```
    AugmentedView augmentedView = new AugmentedView(this);
    augmentedView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    augmentedView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    liveLayout.addView(augmentedView);
```

How can i notify the main class for the changes and pass the List of markers to it?

Comment: super.yourMethod(args ...) ?

Comment: Do you think that your `draw()` method is the right place for collision detection? I'd rather put it into the `update()` method where I update the state.

Comment: Sorry CsBalazsHungary can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry if it is a newbies question but GaborSch there is no update() method. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly , you want to notify the **Activity/Fragment** that contains your **AugmentedView**.

A simple way to do that is by using java callbacks.

// in Activity

```
 //onCreate() ..

AugmentedView augmentedView = new AugmentedView(this);
augmentedView.setOnTouchListener(this);
augmentedView.setCollisionlistener(new Collisionlistener());
augmentedView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
liveLayout.addView(augmentedView);

}
 ..
public class Collisionlistener {
    public void onCollosion (){
     // write code to handle collosion
    }

}


    // in your AugmentedView

    private Collisionlistener mListener;

    public void setCollisionlistener(Collisionlistener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    // your code
    if (collosionDetected && mListener != null) {
        mListener.onCollosion();
    }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks maybe your solution is what i was looking for. As i understand this is similar to the way the threads are working with wait and notify. Am i right?I will test this and i will i accept your answer.